# Effect of soap on the survival of non-enveloped viruses

Tags: virology

As I understand it, non-enveloped viruses are not annihilated by alcohol or have lipid layers to get soluble in soap micelle.

Does soap remove non-enveloped viruses and does hand wash help in their spread?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hand washing with soap is effective at removing non-enveloped viruses. Here is a study showing that washing with soap is effective at disinfecting norovirus, which is a non-enveloped virus: https://aem.asm.org/content/76/2/394